# How can I destring one variable

Tags: string, stata

I have a dataset in Stata with more than 200000 observations and I need to `destring` some   variables.

The command shows that the variable contains nonnumeric characters.

Maybe there´s is one nonnumeric value, but analyzing that by `browse` I believe all the values are numeric.

How can I analyze and fix that?

```
. destring  ampl_log_open_lei, replace
ampl_log_open_lei contains nonnumeric characters; no replace
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tabulate ampl_log_open_lei if missing(real(ampl_log_open_lei))
```

will tabulate observations in which the function `real()` returns missing because non-numeric characters are present.